# Adding a dynamic button to a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

[image: Below is the image decription of what I need]

I am able to get the magnification of the body part where user has tapped. However, as mentioned the text (as "Wrist" in the image) should **dynamically change** depending on the **body part** and it should act as a **button** so that when tapped again it takes user to a different details screen via a function call. How can I achieve this functionality? Code snippets are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve the desired effect with a TapGestureRecognizer?

in viewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapWrist = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedWrist)];
tapWrist.delegate = self;
[bodyView addGestureRecognizer:tapWrist];
```

Add the method:

```
- (void)tappedWrist
{
    // code here
}
```

Don't forget to include:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer  *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

and add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to your header file.